# "gzip --version" gives "Abort trap: 6" in macOS

Tags: macos, gzip

I found that doing `gzip --version` in the terminal on my Mac just gives output `Abort trap: 6`. I came across this because it appears to cause another program to exit when it searches for the installed gzip version. Is there a way to fix gzip? I looked for information about how to reinstall it, thinking that might just fix it, but couldn't find out how to.

Comment: What do you get from `type -a gzip` or `which gzip`? Is this coming from a macOS built-in tool or one you installed separately?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. `type -a gzip` gives `gzip is /sw/bin/gzip` / `gzip is /opt/local/bin/gzip` / `gzip is /usr/bin/gzip` and `which gzip` gives `/sw/bin/gzip`. 

I have not knowingly installed gzip myself.

Comment: `/usr/bin/gzip --version` gives `Apple gzip 272.250.1` and doing this with the other gzip execs give the "Abort trap" message. So perhaps it would work if I can make "gzip" refer to /usr/bin/gzip? Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: I searched for gzip on my OS X 10.6.8 and found only one instance at /usr/bin/gzip. It is a GNU version 1.3.12. On my Mac /usr/bin is the first path.

Comment: After more investigation, it seems the problem execs are associated with fink/macports. Doing a reinstall does not give a working version. I've just renamed the execs so they are not used for now.

Comment: @NevilleHillyer 10.6.8?? As in Snow Leopard?! No one cares what version of gzip was in a macOS release from a decade ago. If you're going to comment on macOS questions in 2019, please reference a 2019 version of macOS, not something from 2009.

Comment: It reminds me I should probably have said that I am using macOS 10.14.5.